# Trouble getting delete link to appear for new records using jQuery/AJAX for creation in Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm creating a todo list app. User has_many tasks through categories. I'm creating new task records for each category through jQuery/ajax in order to make the user experience better. I have a delete link after each task, but on the creation of a new record through ajax, the delete link does not show. If I reload the page it appears. How do I make it so the delete link appears on new records? I've tried following this railscast and have most of it setup except I can't get the delete links to appear: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?autoplay=true.

Here's some of my code:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
   @task = @category.tasks.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @user = @category.user
    @task = @category.tasks.create(params[:task])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { 
       if @task.save
         redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "Task created."
       else
         render 'new'
       end
    }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @task = @category.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @user = @category.user
    @task.destroy
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

new.js.erb:

```
$('.category-<%= @category.id %>-task-link').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

create.js.erb:

```
$('form.new_task').remove();
$('.category-<%= @category.id if @category %>-task-link').show();
$('div.category-<%= @category.id if @category %>-tasks').append('<li class="<%= @task.id if @task %>"><%= j @task.name if @task %></li>');
$('li.task').loadOnCreate();
```

tasks.js (this function should be the one to load in the delete link but I can't figure it out):

```
jQuery.fn.loadOnCreate = function() {
  this.find('a.delete-task').show();
  return this;
}

$(function(){
  $('#new_task').loadOnCreate();
});
```

Thanks.

**Edit**

This is my Rails code for the link:

```
<div class="category-<%= category.id %>-tasks">
    <% category.tasks.each do |task| %>
        <li class="task">
            <%= task.name if task %>
            <%= link_to "x", category_task_path(category, task), class: "delete-task pull-right", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The HTML should look like this for each task:

```
<li class="task">Task<a href="/categories/1/tasks/27" class="delete-task pull-right" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">x</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you add what the html should look like (once you refresh the page)? Where & when is `a.delete-task` inserted before you run `show()`?

Comment: I edited the post with what the HTML code should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `create.js.erb` file:

```
$('div.category-<%= @category.id if @category %>-tasks').append('<li class="<%= @task.id if @task %>"><%= j @task.name if @task %></li>');
```

You are missing the delete link in the `append`. It should actually look like:

```
$('div.category-<%= @category.id if @category %>-tasks').append('<li class="<%= @task.id if @task %>"><%= j @task.name if @task %><%= link_to "x", category_task_path(category, task), class: "delete-task pull-right", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %></li>');
```